# Task Record Type Compact Layout not Displaying as Expected in Publisher Feed

Tags: chatter, activities, custom-actions, compact-layout

I have built an Object-Specific Action on Contact that creates a Task of record type "Payment Entry Task". The action successfully creates the task, and the task is of the correct record type.

But, the post that goes into the feed doesn't display with the correct Compact Layout! I have a different compact layout for this record type, but the feed item is appearing with the system default compact layout.

Even weirder, on Salesforce1, the feed item appears with the correct Compact Layout!

Is there some limitation in Salesforce Classic/Aloha with Task Compact Layouts in the Publisher Feed? Is there a workaround? I just need to get one custom activity field (payment amount) to show up in that feed item.